# Error compiling hexinject on OS X

Tags: macos, makefile, hex

When compiling ***hexinject*** from source on OS X using `make` I get this error:

```
In file included from hexinject.c:8:
In file included from ./hexinject.h:22:
./hexpcap.h:309:12: warning: returning 'const char *' from a function with result type 'const uint8_t *'
      (aka 'const unsigned char *') converts between pointers to integer types with different sign [-Wpointer-sign]
    return raw;
           ^~~
10 warnings generated.
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_field_print", referenced from:
      _tcp_print in hexinject-0a9735.o
      _udp_print in hexinject-0a9735.o
      _icmp_print in hexinject-0a9735.o
      _igmp_print in hexinject-0a9735.o
      _ip_print in hexinject-0a9735.o
      _arp_print in hexinject-0a9735.o
      _ethernet_print in hexinject-0a9735.o
      ...
  "_protocol_16bit_extract", referenced from:
      _ethernet_print in hexinject-0a9735.o
      _llc_print in hexinject-0a9735.o
  "_protocol_48bit_extract", referenced from:
      _ethernet_print in hexinject-0a9735.o
  "_protocol_8bit_extract", referenced from:
      _ip_print in hexinject-0a9735.o
      _isl_print in hexinject-0a9735.o
      _llc_print in hexinject-0a9735.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

I've installed `libpcap` and `tcl`. How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

See here: http://sourceforge.net/p/hexinject/bugs/3/

Open `prettypacket.h` and remove the `inline` keyword from the following functions

`protocol_8bit_extract`,
`protocol_16bit_extract`,
`protocol_48bit_extract`,
and `field_print`

Then compile with `make` as usual